# AMPL: How to code an equilibrium constraint?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ampl

I am trying to code a Maximum Likelihood Estimation problem using AMPL and am unsure as to how to code the **constraint** EQC. I am unsure if I need just one contraint or a system of them  (1 for each player). The constraint is a fixed point iteration.  I have posted the code below:

```
#A constrained optimization formulation for maximum likelihood estimation 
# of a interaction game with Incomplete Information  

#SET up  #
param n; 
set P := 1..n;  # set of players: 
set A := 0..1;  # set of actions: adopt is indexed by 1; not adopt is indexed by 0
param nG;               # number of groups in the data
set G := 1..nG; # G is the set of groups
param x {g in G, i in P};
param d {g in G, i in P};
```

variables to be solved by the optimizer

```
var alpha >= -100, <= 100;    #alpha  is to be estimated 
var beta >= -100, <= 100;      # beta is to be estimated 
var p {g in G, i in P} >=0, <=1;  #probability of choosing action A=1, to be estimated
```

objective function and constraints:

```
maximize Likelihood: sum {g in G, i in P} log(d[g,i]*p[g,i] + (1-d[g,i])*(1-p[g,i]));
subject to EQC {g in G, i in P}: p[g,i] = 1/(1+exp( x[g,i]*alpha + (1/n-1)(sum{g in G, i in P} (p[g,-i]))*beta)) ;

 #equilibrium constraint where the probability of taking action A=1 is given by the logit of linear function of alpha,beta,p -> p[g,-i] is probability of A=1 for all other player's excluding i
```

Thanks very much Stackoverflow